# Narrowing conversion in pair with braced initializer compiling if second attribute is not braced-initialized

Tags: c++, c++11

Since c++11, narrowing conversion is not allowed in [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (including [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)). So basically:

```
char c{1000}; // Does not compile with g++, clang, vc
```

But:

```
std::pair<char, double> p{1000, 1.0};
```

Compiles with all compiler?

But:

```
std::pair<char, double> p{1000, {1.0}};
```

Does not compile with VC (error C2398), gives a warning with clang and compiles silently with g++...

I would have expected VC behavior everywhere, i.e. a non-allowed narrowing conversion throwing an error. Which is compiler is right?

---

On the other hand, none of the variable declarations in the following snippets compile:

```
struct X {
    char c;
    double d;
};

X x1{999, 1.0};
X x2{999, {1.0}};

struct Y {
    char c;
    double d;
    Y (char c, double d) : c(c), d(d) { }
};

Y y1{999, 1.0};
Y y2{999, {1.0}};
```

So one of my guess may be that there is something special about `std::pair`? Something that would also narrowing braced-initialization?

Comment: How pedantic did you set your compiler settings? What standard version did you set them to?

Comment: I think the thing is that the narrowing isn't happening before the constructor; I think you're calling [constructor 3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) here, and the constructor is receiving an `int` and doing the conversion itself. My language lawyer knowledge isn't good enough to confirm this, though.

Comment: @user2357112 I completely missed that constructor... This would perfectly explain why the first code compile without problem (while my custom `struct Y` does not work). But it is still a mystery why the second code raise a warning with clang and an error with VC... Shouldn't the same constructor be called?

Comment: @user2357112 After some tries, I found out that for the second snippet, the "standard" constructor is called `pair(const T1& x, const T2& y);`... But why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. `std::pair<char, double> p{1000, 1.0};` is not diagnosed because it calls the `template<class U1, class U2> pair(U1&&, U2&&)` constructor (with `U1 == int` and `U2 == double`), which is an exact match; the narrowing doesn't happen until you get into the constructor body.
2. `std::pair<char, double> p{1000, {1.0}};` cannot call that constructor because the *braced-init-list* `{1.0}` is a non-deduced context, so you cannot deduce `U2`.

   - In clang/libc++, it calls the `pair(const T1&, const T2&)` constructor; however [clang apparently doesn't consider the conversion needed to create a temporary for reference binding as part of the narrowing check](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8a9895ca4b2ef93). This is probably a bug.
   - GCC/libstdc++'s `pair` has a `template<class U1> pair(U1&&, const T2&)` constructor template, which is a better match. With this constructor, the second argument isn't narrowing, and the first argument is an exact match, so you get no error or warning.

Comment: So GCC "extension" is in contradiction with the standard and VC would be the correct one?

Comment: If I make a [class with the same constructor semantics](http://ideone.com/cBDKCA), the narrowing conversion still takes place. Is there something else that I'm missing? Thanks :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Your constructor does not have the same semantic because it is not templated  (your class is but not your constructor).